# Array of string interpolation to randomize messages

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I'd like to welcome my user with a randomized message, but in every message, it still has to refer to the user to its firstname.

So i wanted to create an array of catchphrases, for instance, such as :

```
const CATCHPHRASES = [
   `Hi ${user}, how you doin' ?`,
   `Have a great day, ${user} !`,
   `Sun is shining, so is your day ${user} !`
];
```

And have a function that give me a random one, filling in the user as props

```
function getIntroTextRandomized(username: string): string {
    // Somehow filling the CATCHPHRASES here with my username props
    return CATCHPHRASES[Math.floor(Math.random() * CATCHPHRASES.length)];
}
```

I can't think of another solution than es6 string interpolation.
thanks for your help

Comment: Just replace the placeholder in the string? Not ES6 but it's the same basic idea for any language you'd use.

Comment: Yep. I think i was overthinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to use `replace` function?

```
const CATCHPHRASES = [
   `Hi :user, how you doin' ?`,
   `Have a great day, :user !`,
   `Sun is shining, so is your day :user !`
];

function getIntroTextRandomized(username: string): string {
    // Somehow filling the CATCHPHRASES here with my username props
    return CATCHPHRASES[Math.floor(Math.random() * CATCHPHRASES.length)].replace(`:user`, username);
}
```

Comment: We have a winner. I like the way the data stays easily readable and ":user" can be replaced by whatever you want to make it easy to understand at first sight.

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of arrow functions which takes `user` as a parameter. Then, pass the `username` as a parameter to the random function selected

```js
const CATCHPHRASES = [
  user => `Hi ${user}, how you doin' ?`,
  user => `Have a great day, ${user} !`,
  user => `Sun is shining, so is your day ${user} !`
];

function getIntroTextRandomized(username) {
  return CATCHPHRASES[Math.floor(Math.random() * CATCHPHRASES.length)](username);
}

console.log(getIntroTextRandomized("john doe"))
```

Comment: That is a cool tips. I haven't though of this. However, the data set seems a bit less readable to me than the @anatolii's answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to retrieve a phrase

```js
const catchphrases = (user, index) => {
    const phrases = [
        `Hi ${user}, how you doin' ?`,
        `Have a great day, ${user} !`,
        `Sun is shining, so is your day ${user} !`
    ];

    return phrases[index || Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length)];
};

console.log(catchphrases('Foo'));
```

Comment: I want to keep my CATCHPHRASES data out of this function. In order to make it more maintainable. That could work thought

Comment: You've accepted the only bad answer. Use adigas if you prefer that... But not a regex here. @LouisLecocq

Comment: Please explain why that wouldn't be the right answer